# How to do multiplication for two 4-bit numbers treating them as polynomials in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cryptography, aes, galois-field

I am simulating a mini AES encryption/decryption algorithm using MATLAB. For this I need to multiply two 4-bit numbers while treating them as polynomials. It goes though some stages, that are, converting to polynomials, multiply the two polynomials, polynomial reduction to lower power if needed using a predefined irreducible  polynomial. Then converting back to 4-bit format.

For instance, multiplying 1011⊗ 0111 is analogous to x3+x+1 ⊗ x2+x+1 The ans is x5+x4+1 has of a power of 5 then you need to reduce it by dividing on the predefined polynomial x4+x+1. The answer will be x2 that is 0100.

I know that there are some functions in MATLAB doing polynomial multiplications but they are kind of general and need some specific function or method to do this.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you obtain x2 from x5+x4+1 and x4+x+1?

Comment: For clarity, which are the functions you already found, and why are they not suitable?

Comment: @LuisMendo when you do long division x5+x4+1/x4+x+1 while adding them in galois field modulo 2, so basically i.e. x4+x4=0 this way the remainder is x2. I have a miniAES short report, a very well known one: 
https://piazza.com/class_profile/get_resource/ixlc30gojpe5fs/iyv0273azwtz4
The link above contains an example for this in section 2.3

Comment: @Daniel I was playing around with gfconv(). However it didn't give me right answers as it seems not to do the reduction according to a specific polynomial. If interested see the example in section 2.3 in the following short report:

https://piazza.com/class_profile/get_resource/ixlc30gojpe5fs/iyv0273azwtz4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polynomial multiplication/division is the same as convolution/deconvolution of their coefficients. Then `mod(...,2)` is applied to the results.

I'm not quite sure that this two-step process is correct for GF; please try with some other polynomials have to see if the results are what you expect:

```
x = [1 0 1 1];
y = [0 1 1 1];
product = conv(x, y);
product = mod(product ,2);
divider = [1 0 0 1 1];
[~, remainder] = deconv(product, divider);
remainder = mod(remainder, 2);
```

This gives

```
product =
     0     1     1     0     0     0     1
remainder =
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
```

Comment: Thank you Luis for your reply. I can understand your explanation on the conv/deconv. However, I did not get the same answer, I literally copied and pasted your lines of codes.

Comment: @AbuZaid Sorry, there were several typos. Please see now